# Enterprise Lookup Tables

Tags: vsto, ms-project

I have Microsoft Project 2010 Server.

How can I read all values defined for enterprise lookup table from inside of Microsoft Project 2010? I use VSTO.

Have already tried Application.GlobalOutlineCodes, Application.ActiveProject.OutlineCodes with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to read the data through PSI - you just call PSI from your VSTO add-on. Of course you can read LookupTable from MS Project, but COM is much slower than PSI calls over WCF or .asmx.

I keep a reference to all enterprise custom fields in my add-ons and lookups for them cached. [Here is a sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg224108%28v=office.14%29.aspx) how to read Custom fields and Lookups for them using PSI

Comment: +1. I think the easiest way to read these is really with SQL queries to the `MSPLT_...` tables in the reporting database, but making SQL calls from VSTO isn't that much better than web service calls.

Comment: If you implement any calls to database from an add-on for any business purposes - you may reuse the same for Lookup queries, in the other case you will have to bring all of the configuration information with the add-on or again query it from PSI